# Disable a button in page1 based on a textbox value from page2 (AJAX, PHP,jQuery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am developing a signup form. And for the 'Username check' feature on username name field I use an AJAX function.

My SIGN UP FORM: page1.php

```
<form id="user-form" method="post">
<input id="txtusername" name="txtusername" type="text"onblur="getResult2(this.value);">
<div id="showusername" class="help-block"></div>
<button type="submit" id="butnid" class="btn btn-success" onclick="check()" >Save User</button>
</form>

<script>
 function check(){
 if(getElementById('showusername').innerHTML=="Username available"){
 document.getElementById("user-form").submit();
 }
 }
</script>
```

Then I use an AJAX function to pass the username entered in the textfield to page2.php, where username check is done.

My AJAX function:

```
// to check whether a user name already exist or not
function getResult2(uname)
{

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()//callback fn
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {

            document.getElementById("showusername").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","page2.php?variable="+uname,true);
    // alert(xmlhttp);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

This works fine & passes the value to  page2.php.
I want to disable the button in page1 when the value of a variable in page2 is 0.

My page2 code.

```
<?php
$un=$_GET["variable"];

//php code takes username from database & runs a for loop to check
//suppose $userName[$i] contains all usernames from database
// x is the number of elements in $username[] array.

for($i=0; $i<x;$i++)
{

if( $un ==  $userName[$i])
    {
        echo 'User name already exist';
        $ret_var=0;
        echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "subject1" id="subject1" value="' . $ret_var . '" />';
?>
<script>
// I want to disable the button in page1 if value of $ret_var is 0.

     $(function(){
     var txt = $('#subject1').val();
     if(txt == 0){
     $('#butnid').prop('disabled', true);
                 }
        });

</script>
<?php
        exit();
    }

}
echo 'User name available';

?>
```

But the button does not get disabled. Any help or suggestions???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

page2.php only executes on the server and does not have access to the DOM on page1.php. So send a simple 1 or 0 back to page1.php by way of the AJAX call, then do the DOM manipulation and error reporting in the AJAX response function.

page2.php:

```
<?php

$un=$_GET["variable"];

//php code takes username from database & runs a for loop to check
//suppose $userName[$i] contains all usernames from database
// x is the number of elements in $username[] array.

for($i=0; $i<$x;$i++)
{

  if( $un ==  $userName[$i] ) {
    echo 0;
    exit;
  }
}
echo 1;

?>
```

And back in the JS code on page1.php:

```
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()//callback fn
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        var username_available = xmlhttp.responseText;
        if ( username_available==0 ) {
          document.getElementById('showusername').innerHTML = 'Username already exists';
          $('#butnid').prop('disabled', true);

        }
        else {
          document.getElementById('showusername').innerHTML = 'Username available';
          $('#butnid').prop('disabled', false);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Exactly what i describe in my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are getting values using `value` .it is not in jquery.
instead you have to use like this

```
$('#subject1').val();
```

Comment: Changed. But still no result. @Manishankar

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong. You can't control contents in page 1 while being in page 2 directly.
You have to check for a value from the session or DB to do such a thing.

Ex: Say you want to turn the background color of page1 while being in the page2:

So you have to have a value in database for that, say iscolor column in color table has this value.
Then you update that value from page2 and page1 continuously checks that value at every each 3 seconds. Then after 3 seconds the moment you change the value from page2 will update the page1's background color.

In your case:
I think possible simple thing is, have that disabling function inside of the ajax success code block and let your page 2 to output a value for that function to check.

Answer (score 0):

You're coming at this the wrong way.

Put your disable in the callback function. Since it appears you're also using jquery, you can see this as such:

```
document.getElementById("showusername").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
if (xmlhttp.responseText == "User name already exist"){
    $('#butnid').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

Comment: You also need to remove all the other stuff from your page2 that you're returning via AJAX on an existing match. To quickly illustrate the point, change the if to match 'User name available' and provide one that doesn't exist. It will disable the button.